# Cannot find request URL with JSON information while web scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Im picking up some python web scraping. 
If I go to this [website](https://bors.e24.no/#!/instrument/ZWIPE-ME.MERK), I want to extract description of the company and the list of investors.

I managed to figure out to go to XHR of Chrome inspect and find the json file for the description. However, I cannot seem to find absolutely any information about where and how it fetches the list of investors (down below where it says TOPP 10).

I have gone through similar questions on stack overflow. [Scraping: cannot access information from web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343740/scraping-cannot-access-information-from-web), [Trying to scrape - no response from XHR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699437/trying-to-scrape-no-response-from-xhr), [Empty value from web scraping with python beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191954/empty-value-from-web-scraping-with-python-beautiful-soup).

```py
url = "https://bors.e24.no/#!/instrument/ZWIPE-ME.MERK"
website_url = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'}).text
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r.json()
```

If I use this url (url = "https://bors.e24.no/server/suggest?group=SEARCH_TICKERS&query=Zwipe"), I can extract the ISIN and description. However, I cannot find any request URL for the TOPP 10 list table.

In the example if this [url](https://bors.e24.no/#!/instrument/ZWIPE-ME.MERK), I expect to see this list:

```
TOPP 10 AKSJONÆRER  INNSIDERE
Ti største eiere    Eierandel
AVANZA BANK AB  16,75%
NORDNET BANK AB 6,78%
SKANDINAVISKA ENSKILDA BANKEN AB    6,77%
ARCANUM EIENDOM AS  5,99%
PHOTON FUTURE LIMITED   5,74%
LAUNCH AS   5,33%
SUNDT AS    5,02%
CONCITO AS  3,36%
TELECOM AS  2,13%
ADVISUM AS  1,66%
```

Here is what I see on my Chrome [image]

Comment: what do the expected results look like? I don't see anything under topp 10. Does it require login?

Comment: I added what I expect to see.

Comment: Does it require login as I don't see that at all ? It is just blank.

Comment: No, I have no login. This is what I see: https://imgur.com/a/jQVBKqs
Then if you scroll down, there is the TOPP 10 list.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the data was behind a web socket.

Chrome Inspect -> Network -> WS (Websocket) [PIC1] -> components -> Headers [PIC2]

When you find the web socket connection url, you can follow the code and receive a pong answer. I also found the messages I need to send to receive the TOPP 10 list in the Messages tab (instead of Headers).

```
ws = create_connection("wss://bors.e24.no/server/components")
message = "ping"
ws.send(message)
While True:
    result =  ws.recv() 
    Print("Received ", result) #receive a pong
```

[image]
[image: wss url]